# Which comes first derivative of force then vector it or derivative of vector force.

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I am trying to calculate $\vec{F}_{ij}$ where

$F=\frac{1}{r^2}$

and $r$ is in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates that are function of $t$ for example $x(t)$.  Then force in vector form  is,

$\vec{F}_{ij}=\frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|^2} =\frac{\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_i}{\big((\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_{i})\cdot(\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_{i})\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

The question is that when I take time derivative of $\vec{F}$  or $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{F}$ then should I take derivative of force and then vector it or should I take derivative of vectored force already?

$\frac{d}{dt}F=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r^2}=-2\frac{\dot{r}}{r^3}$

$\dot{\vec{F}}=-2\frac{(\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_i)(\dot{\vec{r}}_{j}-\dot{\vec{r}}_i)}{\big((\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_{i})\cdot(\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_{i})\big)^{\frac{4}{2}}}$

or

$\dot{\vec{F}}_{ij}=\big(\frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|^2}\big)'$

Comment: What do you mean by “…then vector it”?

Comment: There is misprint in some formulae with $|\vec{r}_{ij}|^2$ instead of $^3$. One can compute $\frac{dF}{dt}=-2\frac{\dot{r}}{r^3}$. There is some analog for vectors. $\frac{d\vec{F}}{dt}=\sum_{\alpha} \frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial r_\alpha}\dot{r}_\alpha$, where $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_{j}-\vec{r}_i$, $\alpha$ is component index. $\frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial x}=\frac{\vec{i}}{r^3}-3x\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5}$. Last expression is correct, if you change square to cube in denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for example that one point is not moving, and the other point is moving in a circle around the first. Then $r = |\vec r|$ is constant, so $dr/dt = 0$, but $\vec F$ is not constant, so $d \vec F/dt \neq 0$. Also in this example, $d \vec F/dt$ isn't in the same direction as $\vec r$ at all; they're perpendicular. So it won't work to find $d\vec F/dt$ from the derivative of $|F| = 1/|r|^2$. We must take the derivative of the vector function.

Note

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left|\vec f(t)\right| = \frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{\vec f(t) \cdot \vec f(t)} = \frac{2 \vec f(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \vec f(t)}{2 \sqrt{\vec f(t) \cdot \vec f(t)}} = \frac{\vec f(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \vec f(t)}{\left|\vec f(t)\right|}$$

So

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \vec F = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^3} = \frac{d}{dt} \left(|\vec r|^{-3} \vec r\right) = -3 |\vec r|^{-4} \vec r \left(\frac{d}{dt}|\vec r|\right) + |\vec r|^{-3} \frac{d\vec r}{dt} $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \vec F = -3 |\vec r|^{-4} \frac{\vec r \cdot \frac{d \vec r}{dt}}{|\vec r|} \vec r + |\vec r|^{-3} \frac{d \vec r}{dt} = -3 \frac{\vec r \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}}{r^5} \vec r + \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{d \vec r}{dt} $$